# Is there a logical reason to have soldiers wear bright uniforms?

Tags: warfare, military, clothing

500 years after a nuclear war, an empire called the Midwestern empire rose.

It has conquered most of the Midwest and surrounding areas. They now set their eyes on California, a state that hasn’t been claimed by any other major faction.

They sent 10 legions of soldiers over to start their invasion, but another government, called the Western Federation, also want to control California.

Negotiations have been attempted, but have not worked. Both side are fully prepped to go to war with each other, and would only surrender if their cities were completely destroyed.

The empire usually fights in tight formations, and use standard laser rifles as their main weapon, but each soldier is equipped with and extra side arm, a small laser pistol, and two gamma grenades, grenades that shoot out radiation. All these supplies weigh about 40 pounds. The laser weapon can only fire 3 shots before it overheats, and they have to wait for the weapon to cool. Because of this, they use volley fire.

The western federation has fewer men than the empire does, their soldiers outnumbering them 10 to 1, they have far superior tech. Each soldier is equipped with a metal exoskeleton that lets them pick up x 30 what they could normally carry. Their armor also can deflect any ballistic weapon, except for a bazooka. Their suits cannot however protect the wearer from radiation. The western federation also has heat vision googles in their suits. Lasers can pierce their amor however. Each soldier is equipped with a laser machine gun, which can shoot 15 rounds without overheating. They also have a standard laser rifle like the empire.

They each have body armor that can disperse the energy from laser weapons and smaller ballistic weapons. And last but not least each soldier wears a bright red uniform.

My question is:

Does it make sense for soldiers to wear bright red uniforms in battle?

Comment: Why is "aesthetics" not a good enough answer for you?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaggy_dog_story

Comment: I'd make a comment about Star Trek redshirts, but that would be cruel....

Comment: People with laser rifles would not stand in tight formations. Tight formations existed when you couldn't instantly kill people at a range of 100 yards plus, muskets and their shooters were not that accurate. But modern firearms and marksmanship  training mean that any such tight formation would be decimated. Hopefully it doesn't take a WWI Battle of the Marne for you nations to figure that out.

Comment: I think gamma grenades are not what do you want to use in the battlefield, especially if you have no dense cover (e.g. lead). The radiation is not a shockwave or flying fragments. The power of radiation shrinks with distance squared. Thus if it is supposed to be instantly lethal within some radius, it still would be still non-instantly lethal in bigger radius and harmful in even bigger radius, making it unsafe to use them.

Comment: Gamma grenades are dirty bombs. They explode like normal grenades but also shootout radioactive particles

Comment: Laser weapons are not as lethal as slug-throwers. Close formation would actually work better as a defense against laser weapons, What you DON'T want is a laser reflecting off the suit of the guy 100 yards away, hitting you. Tight formations would scatter the light harmlessly away. The danger to tight formations is not the lasers (unless they are continuous, and thus very, very high energy) they only create localized pin-point hole damage, leaving the rest of the body intact - a very poor anti-personnel weapon)  but the gamma grenades.  They would take out a tight formation.

Comment: Lasers, as a weapon, make good sights for slug throwers.

Comment: And gamma grenades are only useful if they are RPG's. A person can't throw one far enough away without themselves being killed, And even then, they make the area contaminated enough to keep you out as well. Good for defense, very poor for offense. 'The good news, we eliminated the enemy from the hill. The bad news, the hill is so hot, we can not occupy it.'

Comment: Gamma grenades are like suicide bombs, you only throw it when your going to die

Comment: Also, there are some soldiers with RPG that can wipe the enemy out from far away

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72964/discussion-between-bryan-and-justin-thyme).

Comment: "Laser rifle" does not make sense - "rifle" means "gun with grooves inside to make the projectile rotate for in flight stabilization". It does not work with light, even when rotating the polarization inside the gun.

Comment: It seems that numerous comments and some of the answers got distracted by the details of weaponry and formations, not really addressing the color of the uniform - maybe consider editing this question so that you give minimal information and address your main issue, and then elaborate the additional (future-)historical and tactical details. Personally, I fail to see how the number of gamma grenades per soldiers should have any impact on the color of the uniforms, but YMMV '\_:)_/'

Comment: Where's the Western Confederation?  If California isn't part of the WC, and the MWE has to negotiate with the WC, then it's *between* the MWE and California, meaning that the MWE would first have to conquer the WC.  This, plus the red coats, laser rifles and gamma grenades makes this a prime *poorly thought, cart before the horse* question.

Comment: All this talk of a tight formation and its inadequacy as a real-life tactic leads me to believe you are going for a Star-Wars-esque style-over-substance (or "Rule of Cool" as the TV tropers would say) kind of setup, in which case, as for red uniforms, yeah why the hell not?

Comment: @VolkerSiegel I suspect the correct term would be "laser musket" then?

Comment: @JohnDvorak Yes, or "smoothbore gun". But then, a laser rifle could use rotating polarized light, and be named "rifle" for historic reasons.

Comment: @JohnDvorak The term "smoothbore gun" only makes sense for a gas laser, of course.

Comment: Your soldiers fighting in close formations have a common name to describe the formation: "bigger target".

Answer (score 29):

Not in your scenario, no.

Let's go back to the last standing army that wore bright red and look at the reasons why they did that.

The British Model Army, often referred to as the [Redcoats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_coat_(military_uniform)) originally wore red because it was adopted as a national colour in England. This colour served them well in many situations because of the weapons that were in use at the time.

Bayonets were in common use for melee combat as infantry lines closed in. The bright red attracted the attention of the enemy to be sure, but it also ensured that there were no collateral damage incidents on the field as the other British soldiers could tell themselves apart more readily.

Even in ranged combat with muskets, the range and accuracy of these weapons meant that being seen at a distance was less of an issue because it didn't mean that you could be hit, and the black powder being used at the time meant that there was a lot of smoke on a battlefield, and the red uniforms meant that the musketeers didn't aim at a moving shape close to them that turned out to be their own people.

High velocity rifles (snipers), long range weapons, and sneak attack tactics put and end to all that and the British stopped issuing these uniforms at the beginning of WWI.

Your laser rifles and handguns are effectively massively long range weapons. Lasers don't suffer from wind resistance, gravity, or any of the other factors that affect bullets in any meaningful way<sup>1</sup> so if you can see a bright red uniform on the horizon, technically you can hit it. This makes every soldier in your army a sniper, and that also means that the best defence any opponent has against you is not being seen.

The only *possible* scenario I can think of is that the red uniforms are only red because of a refractive effect caused by an ultra-reflective crystalline lattice built into their uniforms, designed to refract and dissipate incoming laser fire.

Scientifically, this seems like a very bad idea, but then so do combat lasers. The red could be because the coats are designed to optimise reflection at a specific frequency, which matches most military lasers. That said, changing the chemical frequency of a combat laser would have to be a simple thing to do for this very reason. Still, it's a possibility.

---

<sup>1. Of course, being in an atmosphere does mean that your laser can attenuate through refraction. Lasers would therefore be 'tighter' in space because there is less to get in the way of the photons to break the coherence of your laser. That said, in practical terms, the refraction of a military laser in the Earth's atmosphere is still less likely to cause range issues that would be material in a situation where ground combat is still a thing.</sup>

Comment: `the best defence any opponent has against you is not being seen.` mandatory british video: https://youtu.be/ifmRgQX82O4

Comment: The other reason for uniforms in the "national" colours was to rapidly identify deserters, since running around in the rear area in a red/blue/white/green coat made you stand out among civilians. Running around in your underwear after shedding the uniform would also make you stand out among the population.

Comment: There is another scenario: to show power. Sometimes it is actually a purpose to "show off" and be as visible as possible. If only to impose your opponent, and gain confidence in your own army.

Comment: Lasers are subject to gravity. I admit it's not enough to "suffer".

Comment: Lasers do suffer from [beam divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beam_divergence). So a laser gun would not necessarily be an ultra-long-range weapon, though you could arrange for it to be one if it worked better for the fiction.

Comment: Upvoting for mentioning being able to distinguish your side from your opponents. Technically you can do this without differing colors, but this is always the reason that springs to mind for me with this scenario.

Comment: Also, red was teally, really inexpensive compared to other colors thanks to a cactus parasite from the new world that produces red dye (forget the name)

Comment: @volker if you unroll the equator into a straight line and 1g of gravity, you will actually get 8 cm drop from end to end just because of the gravity. The good news is that the photons your rifle's scope uses experience the same drop, so your aim would actually be on point. And it also works in even more extreme environments such as hovering over  (not orbiting!) a non-rotating black hole.

Comment: Alternative take:  perhaps, due to the Heat Vision goggles mentioned by OP, "camouflage" is useless.  As such, we're back to "don't shoot your allies!" (a.k.a. [IFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identification_friend_or_foe)).  Red is bright, and easy to identify.  Potentially the material/dye also has a specific [spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum) signature that the headsets can distinguish from "other" redshirts too to muddle any enemy attempts to "blend in"

Comment: Camouflage is never useless. Even if it only prevents a split second of recognition out of the corner of the eye when they're not wearing the goggles, it's worth it.

Answer (score 21):

Your soldiers might wear red if they *want* to be obvious and stand out. Think of the stormtroopers in Star Wars. They value the fear inspired by their reputation more than they do camouflage, so they wear recognizable uniforms to more easily inspire that fear.

This mostly makes sense when your soldiers are going to be up against significantly weaker forces most of the time.

Comment: Well, yes they are

Comment: Or, the Red Baron painting his aircraft red so as to make his presence obvious.

Comment: I am pretty sure stormtroopers were designed for snow combat. Look at all the tech they have

Answer (score 11):

Theres a few things that need to be necessary for your idea to make sense. First is that Napoleonic tight formation style battle maneuvers were a product of the weaponry of the era. Muskets had a phenomenally low rate of fire and were not especially accurate. Commanders had to group companies of men together in order to minimize drawbacks of the low fire rate and unreliable accuracy of the era's weaponry's through sheer volume of fire. If you have laser weapons that can only fire say, 3 times every 60 seconds, then it might make sense. for reference to Napoleonic era muskets, 2 companies of men might line up 50 yards apart and volley fire at each other for up to 8 hours and suffer only a few dozen gunshot casualties each. In the Napoleonic era up through to modern times rifle fire has been a minority of combat wounds, Artillery has been the primary casualty producer (aside from disease.) Problem with "laser musketry" is that then the audience starts asking why at that point nobody is using gunpowder anymore, since its easier to manufacture and making machine guns is actually so easy you could do it in your garage (FYI super illegal, don't try to do this.)The most logical would be to go the "high tech compounds and armor manufacturing means that bullets don't work anymore" route. Perhaps the laser weapons are highly powerful but suffer from over-heating, require frequent focusing-lens and power pack changes, and are not particularly reliable. Keep in mind the back scatter heat and energy from a laser weapon that powerful would produce plasma blooming in the atmosphere generating a LOT of heat, electromagnetic phenomenon. Maybe this has a cumulative effect in degrading weapons limiting rate of fire, making aiming difficult, and limiting range (Plasma blooming disrupts beam cohesion). the only reason such bulky cumbersome weapons are used is because that while it may be hard to hit a target, at least when you do hit something it actually does something instead of just bouncing off the armor.

As far as brightly colored uniforms, if there are lasers and miniaturized gamma radiation sources and such then one would assume that use of thermal optics, radar, or other high-tech scanning and optical enhancement devices would be fairly common. Perhaps the color of a uniform doesn't really matter when even if you evade regular visual detection your enemy still has you on radar, FLIR, IR, UV and LADAR all at the same time. In such a battle field maybe there just isn't any reason your soldiers cant be all painted up in the bright colors of the empire since detection devices are so good hiding simply isn't very possible.

Comment: You make a good point about the rate of fire of laser weapons. a slower rate of fire makes concentrating your weaponry advantageous. However, it would also make the gamma grenades far more effective. What you gain, you loose. What you say about slug throwers is actually very pertinent. Slugs have greater inertia, and thus a wider damage area. Lasers can be effectively blocked using ceramic shielding. Repeated slugs with enough inertia transfer the energy to the ceramic shield, and then transfer it to whatever is below.

Comment: ctd  Lasers make very inefficient anti-personnel weapons. The damage is caused strictly by localized heat. No impact damage. No broken bones. A laser would make a pin-point hole in a shoulder, a slug would shatter the entire shoulder.

Comment: It doesn't matter (+1) also because wars with those weapons will not be fought in "tight formations". Whatever isn't nuked from orbit is mopped up by the aircav. The only thing left for infantry to do is clear out people hiding in holes. 'stand-up-fights' ended with the invention of the machine gun.

Comment: @JustinThyme, a human is an ugly bag of mostly water.  Guess what happens when you heat water in a bag?  You get a steam explosion.  Shoot someone in the shoulder with a high-powered laser, and you don't get a "pin-point hole", you get a small crater.

Comment: @Mark they do something like that now, but not with laser beams as most sci-fi portrays.  It is being pushed as a deterrent which burns the skin, but can be lethal if used continuously in confined spaces.

Comment: @Mark nope, does not work like that, Laser eye surgery, for instance, does not blow up the eye.

Comment: Not all lasers are the same power level, or wavelength. The military is in fact working on a pulsed energy laser that rapidly vaporizes material to produce a loud and potentially lethal explosion. They plan to use it as a less than lethal deterrent that can be turned up to produce lethal results if necessary.

Comment: @JustinThyme, actually, laser eye surgery *does* blow up the eye.  It's just that it uses a small enough beam and brief enough pulses that the resulting micro-explosions re-shape the lens rather than destroying the eye.

Answer (score 10):

The reason modern soldiers wear camouflage is because not being seen gives you an advantage in combat. Wearing bright colors can give the enemy the necessary split-second advantage to shoot you before you shoot them. Personal anecdote: One time I was playing Paintball. Everyone wore old camo overalls provided by the paintball range. But one guy in the opposite team insisted on wearing a red sweater over it (for science? lost a bet? no idea). That guy got hit more than the rest of his team combined.

But what if AI assistance systems have become so good that camouflage becomes useless? What if every soldier had an augmented reality headset. The headset has advanced sensors and recognition software which is very good at finding and identifying targets. Enemies, allies and non-combatants get highlighted in bright colors. Wearing camouflage doesn't help - the sensors and the AI system are too advanced to be confused by that.

Uniform color would then no longer have any impact on survivability. So your army would focus on the other purpose of uniforms: Instilling a sense of order and camaraderie among the soldiers. In that case, uniform design is simply a fashion choice.

Comment: +1, seems reasonable, if you fight in tight formation or wear a bulky exoskeleton you might be easy to spot regardless of the uniform. Those laser rifles presumably also have some sort of an electronic sight. It probably has thermal imaging.  The big question is why fight laser rifles in close formations at all? A similar tech laser system attached to a vehicle could probably have enough power and cooling to mow down entire formation in short order. And having its own wheels, be cheaper to field.

Comment: @VilleNiemi Indeed. The more advanced your technology, the less sense it makes to fight in close formations. But that plothole is not the subject of the question.

Answer (score 8):

**The uniforms are red because the material that gives the uniforms their protective properties is red.**

[image: synthetic rubies]
https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Loose-Gem-3-8mm-Created-Synthetic_60118321103.html

Your uniforms confer some protection against ballistic and laser weapons.  If they were made a fabric which incorporated synthetic ruby (corundum) they would be red.  Ruby is extremely hard and durable as well as translucent and refractive.  Ruby is not an outrageous choice as a basis for a super durable protective fabric - both against impacts as well as light-based attacks.

The soldiers do not care enough to paint or cover the uniforms to make them a color other than red.  They are uninterested in concealment because the nature of their combat makes that pointless or an impossibility. So the uniforms are the color of the material they are made from.

Sapphire is a cousin of ruby and also extremely hard if you need some blue uniforms.

Comment: Great idea - you can augment the "the soldiers do not care enough to paint their uniform" with some future technology - e.g. if everyone have IR / sonar / radar goggles (with standard FoF and BC augmentations, obviously), then pigments-based camouflage is just a silly notions from ages past

Comment: Huh? Did I read pricing right? 1000 tiny rubies for 10 dollars? I'll have to remember that, I could imagine a few decorative uses.

Comment: @M i ech - I was surprised too!  Synthetic sapphires are comparably cheap.

Answer (score 5):

Re "The empire usually fights in tight formations, and use standard laser rifles...": I'm assuming the folks they're fighting have those laser rifles &c, or at least some sort of ranged weapon?  Then the only reason for fighting in a tight formation, or wearing bright uniforms, is that the Empire needs to kill off its surplus population, WWI trench warfare style.

Really, formation fighting, like bright colored uniforms, went out with the Redcoats at Lexington & Concord (American Revolution, April 1775, for non-US people), even if some military minds haven't quite accepted the fact yet.  (I'm perhaps a bit prejudiced here: in boot camp, two centuries later, they still had us practicing close-order drill, instead of things that might have been of some use in real combat :-()

Comment: Drilling is designed to install teamwork, unit cohesion and immediate obedience to orders, which has *very* clear use in real combat.

Comment: @Thucydides: Doesn't work that way, at least in my experience.  It's more the brass being interested in fighting the wars of the last century.  Honestly, I think some of them would only be happy if we went back to the Greek phalanx.  (And I wasn't intending to play on your username when I wrote that, really :-))

Comment: Completely wrong. Tight formation was still a thing during Napoleonic wars and later. It wasn't until breech loading rifles that tight formation started falling out of use. Tight formation + bayonet are a defence against cavalry, as long as infantry does not have firearms with enough RoF and range to mow down charging cavalry, they need to fight in tight formation or get slaughtered.

Comment: tight drilling also comes into use in modern military not in combat but in getting large groups moved around and on and off transports. Although drilling rarely focus on this.

Comment: The purpose of close-formation drills is to instill a sense of unity - to get everyone working together, as a homogeneous unit. If you are out of step in a military drill, everyone stumbles. That's the point. In modern warfare, you absolutely depend on the other person doing exactly what is required by the entire formation. Strict adherence to the drill. Step-step-step in time with the beat. In operations, you follow the check-list script, step-by-step. in co-ordination with everyone else.

Comment: If the Redcoats had had cavalry with them at Lexington, the result would have been a resounding defeat of the Minutemen.  Until you develop breech-loading rifles, the only defense infantry in the field has against cavalry is a tight formation with pointy objects on sticks.

Comment: @M i ech:  That military commanders stuck with formation fighting through the Napoleonic wars (and to a degree up to WWI) only demonstrates their essential conservatism, and preference for "show" (ever spit-polished your combat boots?) over effectiveness.

Comment: @Mark: I don't know about that.  While I have never participated in a calvary charge (on either end), I do ride horses.  Riding at speed through a heavily-wooded area (such as much of the eastern US was then) is not easy.  Holding a calvary charge together would be impossible, IMHO.  (Which perhaps explains why the Redcoats didn't have calvary.)  So your Minutemen are dispersed behind trees, wearing drab clothing, and firing into a massed formation of Redcoats.  How does a calvary charge rout them out?

Comment: @jamesqf, a thundering charge isn't the only way for cavalry to fight, it's just the one that makes for good stories and dramatic paintings.  One-on-one, a guy on a horse with a sword beats a guy who's just missed his shot with a musket.  Minutemen beat Redcoats by being able to run away and pick another firing spot; against cavalry, they don't have the speed advantage they need to do that.

Comment: @Miech even as late as ww1 the French wanted long rifles as volley firing in ranks was still "they thought" a requirement

Comment: @jamesqf You have no understanding of XIX century warfare, or maybe your hatred for drills colours your judgement. Or maybe you watched too many Hollywood films, which always go out of their way to show worst tactics imaginable. Breech loading rifles started entering military service about ~1850 and Autro-Prussian war (1866) was the first war where breech-loaders saw real use. It was a decisive victory for Prussians specifically because breech-loaders used by Prussians were THE FIRST EVER hard counters to both cavalry and tight formations. Modern infantry tactics developed only after this war.

Comment: @M i ech: You are correct in that my experience relates to XXth century warfare.  It is not derived from Hollywood films, since I seldom watch movies (or TV), and never war movies.

Answer (score 3):

Bright uniforms? Possibly but the reasons I am giving is a stretch. Since bright colors reflect more light, bright uniforms might be contributing to the dispersion of radiation from lasers and the gamma grenades. However, gamma grenades I assume would emit gamma rays would not help much since it is very hard to make a gamma ray mirror. The lasers on the other hand could be infrared lasers in which case bright red might make sense but higher-frequency lasers such as x-rays could also be used.

On the other hand, if the weapons being used create a lot of dust or smoke (i.e. the gamma grenades could shoot out radiation by dispersing radioisotope dust/smoke), bright uniforms might be needed to see each other similar to European battles before smokeless gunpowder.

Answer (score 3):

**Rules of Engagement and the lessons of history.**

This is a post-nuclear war world. The soldiers are armed with deadly weapons. There is a global prohibition against civilian casualties and collateral damage. The mass destruction accompanying the nuclear war of five centuries has created an indelible lesson in the need to restrict combat and confine battlefields to much smaller areas.

Fighting units are compelled by law and treaty to form up in small, compact groupings to make their exchange of fire less discriminate and less likely to harm civilians or destroy civilian property. Military personnel are also required by law and treaty to wear distinctive clothing to make them readily identifiable.

Therefore, when the forces of the Midwestern Empire are abroad civilians will not wear red for their own safety and protection.

Comment: During the first stages of the American Civil War, when the sides lined up against each other, civilian spectators would often come out and cheer their side on, like they do at football games. Pre-1870's, European war was pretty much a game, a spectator sport. The soldiers used bright uniforms for the same reason football teams use coordinating uniforms.  They identified the home team from the away team. This pretty much ended when weaponry became more deadly. But by then, we had the news media to allow spectating and cheering from a distance. And, we now had the Olympics.

Comment: But, who enforces those laws?  What happens if someone does kill noncombatants?  Is there enough social exchange to make them lose trade and allied support rather than become the de facto rulers through intimidation and terror?  Using any weapon which poisons the area rather than simply kills would seem to prohibit use of the weapon in certain areas which are yet viable moreso than limit its use in regards to the amount or class of people — unless combatants only fight on wasted terrain.  Why would they be fighting there, then?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer - the following is an "a guy once told me" answer which I haven't verified, so do your own research before quoting.

However, I was once told by an ex-British soldier with a strong interest in military history that the reason the British Army historically wore bright red uniforms was to prevent enemies from seeing how many troops there were, and/or from distinguishing individual soldiers.  So this was partly so that the enemy would think there were more British soldiers than there were (psychological warfare) and partly so that they could not identify they soldiers as (from a distance, or through a telescope), all the soldiers would blend into one indistinguishable splodge.

To me, however, these seem like minor advantages compared to the much bigger advantages gained from camouflage, which probably explains why the latter replaced the former.

Comment: So, you're saying they were employing the Zebra Defense?

Comment: @Paul yeah, basically.  Hadn't thought of it that way, but yes.  (According to this guy).

Comment: But why red? This would apply to any color.

Comment: @JustinThyme, because they had access to a cheap bright-red dye.

Comment: I’ve heard a similar apocryphal story that it was to hide injuries.

Comment: Doesn't seem at all plausible

Comment: Body
 Add picture

Answer (score 0):

**Status or the Mission - perhaps more important than life, especially if camouflage makes no difference**

We sometimes make the mistake that the military wants to 'save lives of soldiers'. To an extent this is true, however overall the mission takes priority.

If by wearing a bright colour, such as red, they create a uniform, strong physical presence to others, including other armies, you might create a strong psychological effect that may serve the government / military more than saving it's own lives. It may also be a good recruitment drive too and give the nation identity.

There could also be advanced technology that could target soldiers with no-error, available cheaply to all armies. In this case there would be no reason to be camouflaged, and so the soldiers might as well wear red for other purposes as above.

Answer (score -3):

If, because of genetic effects from the nuclear war, everyone were red-green color blind, then red would be the perfect camouflage. **Edit** Hunting vests are no longer red because color blind people can not distinguish them against a green background. Too many hunters were thus being shot wearing bright red vests.

It is also the color that is least seen from a distance. Blue light penetrates the atmosphere better than red light, that  is **why distant mountains** are blue.  **edit**  it is the blue light from the distant mountains that penetrates the atmosphere. **EDIT** See [How to instantly add depth to your mountains in acrylic landscape painting](http://willkempartschool.com/how-to-instantly-add-depth-to-your-mountains-in-acrylic-landscape-painting/)

**EDIT** This, of course, because a blue light photon has more energy than a red light photon. It's all about wave length,

Most red traffic lights actually have blue in them, so they are seen from a distance. Same with police and emergency vehicle flashing lights.

Winter road vehicles (snow plows and sanders) use flashing blue lights, because red just isn't visible enough in inclement weather.

And, of course, there is the psychological factor - red is associated with anger and aggression. It also signifies avoidance, danger.

Comment: *Blue light penetrates the atmosphere better than red light*

That is exactly the opposite of true. The atmosphere *scatters* blue light more effectively than red, which is why the sky is blue. Red will transmit farther. That's why sunsets are red--the blue light is filtered out of the image of the sun when it has to travel longer distances through the atmosphere, leaving only red behind.

Blue light *does*, however, travel farther in water, which absorbs red light relatively quickly.

Comment: @ Logan R. Kearsley  Sorry, the facts say otherwise. See [this](https://van.physics.illinois.edu/qa/listing.php?id=2629) , for instance

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley that link that you give doesn't seem relevant, unless you assume that since blue light is more energetic than red light then it automatically penetrates the atmosphere better.

Comment: @ John Coleman That's exactly what it means. Blue light has more energy than red light, thus it has greater penetrating power. Even in radio waves, the higher the frequency, the greater the penetrating power.

Comment: If everyone's red-green colorblind, solid red would be useless.  Armies have often used colorblind individuals as scouts, spotters, and snipers because, for unknown reasons, colorblindness is associated with an increased ability to see through camouflage.

Comment: @JustinThyme *Blue light has more energy than red light, thus it has greater penetrating power* Physics doesn't work that way... which you can verify by *looking at a freaking sunset*. If that were true, the ozone layer would be worthless, because UV would automatically have more penetrating power. But it *doesn't*. The properties of the material medium matter, not just photon energy--ozone absorbs ultraviolet, nitrogen and oxygen scatter blue, and red travels farther through the atmosphere in straight lines. See, e.g., http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/General/BlueSky/blue_sky.html

Comment: Incidentally, the reason many traffic signals include blue lights in tandem with the red ones has nothing to do with being seen from *farther away*, and has nothing to do with the inherent properties of the color--it's because the *blue* lighting elements are *structurally* designed differently, so that they can be seen from more angles, as an assistance to police officers watching for red-light violations..

Comment: @Logan R. Kearsley Not the blue lights BESIDE the red traffic lights, the red lens itself contains blue filters as well as red. Look closely at a red light. It is not pure red. It is red-blue. Under some conditions, the fringes will actually look purple.

Comment: In addition to holding on to an inadequate (scatter-free) theory as to why the sky is blue, the discussion is a bit besides the point. What colors the *human* eye can best see at a distance has little to do with fundamental physics but a great deal to do with evolutionary biology. The human retina can see some colors better than it can see others. If human evolution had been tightly constrained by the need to survive the predations of giant purple people eaters, we might very well have eyes which are very good at seeing purple at a distance.

Comment: At the risk of beating a dead horse: on a cloudless day there is a clear gradient of blue, most intense at the zenith and paler as you go towards the horizon. Your theory would seem to predict the opposite gradient (even greater filtering of red closer to the horizon would make the blue more vivid there, but less filtering when you look straight up rendering it less vivid).

Comment: I see the confusion. It was inexcusable carelessness on my part to use the term 'sky'. I was thinking the blue light from the distant mountains that penetrates the atmosphere better, I should not have used the term 'sky' in this context. The sky is blue because blue light has the shortest wavelength, and thus the most energy, and is therefore scattered the most. We see 'blue sky' because the higher energy higher frequency blue light is reflected (scattered) off the atmospheric particles. We see mountains as blue for another reason - the penetrating energy of the higher frequency blue light.

Comment: @JustinThyme [Why isn't the sky violet then?](https://xkcd.com/1145/)

Comment: It isn't the mountains that look blue, it's all that "blue air" in between. [Here is a perfect example of the difference between penetration and scattering.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering#/media/File:Why_is_the_sky_blue.jpg)
You are mistaking correlation with causation. Blue has a shorter wavelength than red, and therefore more energy. But it is the wavelength that translates to scattering/absorbtion/transmission.
My walkie-talkie penetrates the wall but unless I throw my flashlight, it's stopped by the wall.

Comment: @chew socks See if I can get this in the char count. Light does not reflect or refract or scatter. Nothing 'bounces' it off. Light is absorbed by the  particle and then re-radiated. It does not have to be re-radiated at the same frequency and energy that it hit the particle. It so happens that with atmospheric particles the blue frequency imparts energy to the particle and the particle re-radiates it as blue light. Unique to this energy and frequency. The atmosphere contains enough water so that the atmosphere acts like water. Blue light penetrates further through water.

Comment: There is no good reason why every particle does not act like glass - that is, the light goes right through it. Particles are mainly empty nothingness. Opaqueness and reflection are a function of the molecule/atom's method  to capture light energy and re-radiate it in a particular direction. Light either travels in a 'straight' line (gravitational effects aside) or it hits something and is converted to energy in the atom/molecule. What that atom/molecule does with the energy  is what causes light to either 'through', be 'refracted'',or be 'reflected'.

Comment: Blue light, because of its high energy and high frequency, acts very differently than red light at a lower energy and frequency.

Comment: It is the same basic principle (absorption and re-radiation of light energy) but different application. That is why in my carelessness and rush to post, I mixed them up. The sky is blue, because of the frequency and energy of blue light, and the distant mountains are blue, because of the frequency and energy of blue light. At night, in misty or dusty conditions, one sees the flashing blue lights before the flashing red lights when approaching emergency vehicles.

Comment: @Mark Interesting. I have never heard that before. But if true, it could be that people who are color blind use other than color cues to distinguish figure-ground. Contrast, for instance. Would a color-blind see a red coat against a green background? Hunting accidents, and why hunting vests are no longer red, would argue against it.

Comment: @Mark A good landscape painter actually DOES add violet to the mountains to make the painting [realistic](https://books.google.ca/books?id=ZbXDAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA69&lpg=PA69&dq=painting+violet+mountains+in+landscape+painting&source=bl&ots=rWxM2o1ko-&sig=srzpGzTqglvgyNXX7Hn1JZi1UIU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjp5pTjmJ_ZAhXD44MKHUNQAIkQ6AEITDAL#v=onepage&q=painting%20violet%20mountains%20in%20landscape%20painting&f=false). Violet is made by adding red to blue, which is not accurate to a true light spectrum violet. I suppose purple (red/blue mix) and violet light from the spectrum are not really the same.